# Public ip address to get country in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a user's country based on IP address in web api. Using userhostaddress it returns a Private IP not their public IP.

This is what I've been trying:

```
string clientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
string nowip = null;
nowip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nowip)){
    nowip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
}

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string ipAddress = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: May we see what you've been trying?

Comment: string clientAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

Comment: nowip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nowip))
            {
                nowip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
            } WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org");

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

Comment: You should edit that into your question.

Comment: There are a number of questions that can likely help you get your clients' IPs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285957/how-to-get-public-ip-address-of-a-user-in-c-sharp , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948201/asp-net-get-external-ip-address , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620932/get-users-ip-address .

Comment: but i already tried not worked

Comment: There are multiple solutions in those answers, you only showed two attempts above. For instance did you try: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`?

Comment: used already see the first line it returns only private ip not publc

Comment: any answers waiting for help