# How to get client Ip Address without using header in Java

Tags: apache, tomcat, ip-address

I am using apache-tomcat for app server and web server. 
I want to keep track of the IP addresses of the systems that access my app server. But unfortunately the only way to get the IP address of the client systems and not the IP of web server we have to use Header X-Forwarded-For'. But I do not use X-Forwarded-For header, as it might expose the IP and cause security threat.

Is there any other way to accomplish this without 'X-Forwarded-For' header or Will it be secure to use this without any security compromises. Thanks in advance!

Ref: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

There is no de facto standard for this.

Either `X-Forwarded-For` is used or `getRemoteAddress` is used.

Hope this link is helpful.
[what is the right way to get request's ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip)

As far as security is concerned, I think this is the normal convention so it would be fine.