# the code for finding ip address returning null always

Tags: java, servlets

I know this question is raised too many times ago but my problem is different.
I want to detect the ip address of client which can be anywhere in the world. I googled and found some way but it is not working.

When I ask our network administrator, he told me that our proxy server has ip 192.xxx.xxx.xxx and for the outside of our company network the ip is 180.xxx.xxx.xxx which is bind to our proxy server's ip address[192.xxx.xxx.xxx]

Here is the code that I tried. This code resides in servlet.
All are returning null. 
Thanks in advance...

```
String ipAddress;
ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

System.out.println(ipAddress);
       if (ipAddress == null) {  
           ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
           System.out.println(ipAddress);
       }

       ipAddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
       System.out.println(ipAddress);
        ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
        ipAddress = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
        ipAddress = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
        ipAddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
        ipAddress = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip

Comment: The only person can can reliably answer this question is the administrator of your company proxy. But you should tell him why you need that information and ask him what he can do.

Comment: Are you running this from localhost?

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of code to get the ipAdd, not sure but might work for you !!!

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("True-Client-IP");

if(ipAddress == null || ipAddress.trim().length() == 0)
{
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

}
```