# I get local ip address from request

Tags: java

I am using Spring boot and when i try to get user ip from request like this :

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

I get 127.0.0.1 for every user.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? What's your whole code ? What's a user ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350318/what-is-the-right-way-to-get-requests-ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually means that there is a server in front of it from. In those cases the original IP address is often passed along in a request header, called "x-forwarded-for".