# Servlet - get client public IP

Tags: java, servlets, network-programming

I'm trying to get client `public` ip address via servlet as below:

```
        String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        System.out.println("1. ip: "+ip);
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");
        }
        System.out.println("2. ip: "+ip);
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        }
        System.out.println("3. ip: "+ip);
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        }
        System.out.println("4. ip: "+ip);
        if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }
        System.out.println("4. ip: "+ip);
```

but this only able to return the localhost IP, as you see in below output:

```
1. ip: null
2. ip: null
3. ip: null
4. ip: null
4. ip: 127.0.0.1
```

Any help?

Comment: Couldn't find any work out there.

Comment: How about an accepted answer ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363069/how-can-i-retrieve-ip-address-from-http-header-in-java/10363109#10363109

Comment: I already have this, it only returns the localhost ip.

Answer (score 2):

It depends from proxy server/load balancer and their configurations.
In most cases it is possible to get IP by

```
request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")
```

or

```
request.getHeader("x-real-ip")
```

In case when before your server you have proxy server, make sure that proxy pass headers to your server, e.g. in case of nginx it should look like

```
server {
  server_name  domain.com;
  ...
  location /path-to-server {
    ...
    proxy_pass  localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: This only returns `null` value

Comment: which proxy server you have before your server, e.g. nginx? if nginx make sure that it pass all headers to your server.

Comment: did nginx pass all headers? can you try enable access log in nginx and check client ip, then in your server dump whole request header and check what is inside.

Comment: actually I can see that the `tomcat` is not able to send the header to the app.. when I test that with `curl` I get a null header

Answer (score 0):

I do like this,you can have a try

```
public String getIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {      
   String ip = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");      
   if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
       ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");      
   }      
   if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
       ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");      
   }      
   if(ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {      
       ip = request.getRemoteAddr();      
   }      
   return ip;      
}
```