# How can i trace the users IP address and Windows Login name from a java web application

Tags: java, ip, web-hosting

How can i trace the users IP address from a web application

i tried with some existing methods in java. but its showing servers IP address

```
    InetAddress ip;
    String hostname;
    ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    hostname=ip.getHostName();  // to get system name
    ip.getHostAddress() // to get IP address
```

But its showing server IP for all login traces..

Answer (score 2):

You can get the request IP from the request header

```
 String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  

 if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }
```

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

Comment: how to get System name ?

Comment: @DileepKumar String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");

Comment: I tried request.getHeader("User-Agent"); but i am getting like this  -Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36

Comment: @DileepKumar "Windows NT 6.1"  is windows. Parse the string.

Comment: i want system login name (i mean windows login name)

Answer (score 1):

If you using your application on any webserver then use header to get ipAddress

```
String ipAddressFrmHed = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") != null ? request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR") : request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Better Explained your question HERE

[How can I retrieve IP address from HTTP header in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363069/how-can-i-retrieve-ip-address-from-http-header-in-java)