# Cannot load page via HTTPS using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https

As the title says. I need to load a page on https on my browser. I'm using this C# code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [RequireHttps]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult WordpressIframe()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Account/WordpressIframe.cshtml");
    }
```

When my page is deployed on IIS, it gives me this error:  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[image]

Sorry that the image is on spanish. Please help

Comment: I strongly suspect that it is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849776/remote-require-https-mvc-5/26854689#26854689 (or at very least I have investigation steps in the answer).

Comment: What is your network log for this request? You can get in in Fiddler or in browser usin F12