# Defintion for the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header

Tags: http, http-headers, x-forwarded-for

Where can I find a definition for the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header? Most sites refer to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) site. Here the X-Forwarded-For format is described as `X-Forwarded-For: client, proxy1, proxy2`. I'm curious what valid strings for one entry can be. Are following examples valid entries?

- `192.0.2.60`
- `192.0.2.60:58074`
- `2001:db8:cafe::17`
- `[2001:db8:cafe::17]:47011`
- `"[2001:db8:cafe::17]:47011"`

Answer (score 1):

There is none as it is a non-standard header that cannot be found through the [message header registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml). So your examples are all valid if you decide them to be valid.

If you want to go by a standard, [RFC 7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) is providing a standardized mechanism in place of `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed here: [What is a full specification of X-Forwarded-Proto HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111080/what-is-a-full-specification-of-x-forwarded-proto-http-header)

You can also have a look at section 7.4 of [rfc7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239).