# Webclient not using proxy settings

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient

I've been using the .NET WebClient class, but whenever I try to use the proxy settings (just specifying one of the IP addresses without any credentials here http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) the target server still thinks I'm on the normal IP address.

By "normal" I mean the static IP address provided by our ISP rather than the proxy IP.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("122.72.11.200");
Console.Write(wc.DownloadString("hostip.info"));
```

Am I missing something super-obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Many (non-anonymous) proxies will send a header containing the original IP address in the request. See [Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul)

Perhaps hostip.info is using such a header to find out your IP address. You could check what headers are sent by the proxy by making a request to an HTTP echo service, e.g. http://scooterlabs.com/echo instead of http://hostip.info .

BTW: How do you conclude from the output (an html page?) that hostip.info is returning your 'normal' IP address. And shouldn't a full URI like `http://www.hostip.info` be passed as an argument to `DownloadString()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing your own external IP because you are not giving a port.
Internally the `WebProxy(Address)` calls the `CreateProxyUri()` function, to turn your Ip into an uri. This would mean that from here on out port 80 would be used to do the requests, while your proxy most likely required a different port (looking at the site you provided, this seems to be the case)

```
private static Uri CreateProxyUri(string address) {
    if (address == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (address.IndexOf("://") == -1) {
        address = "http://" + address;
    }
    return new Uri(address);
}
```

You could fix it by calling the `WebProxy(address, port)` constructor instead with the proper port. Or by appending `:port` to the address string, where port depicts a port number.