# get_host() vs META['REMOTE_ADDR'] for security reasons

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a Django project where users will have custom info given to them depending on their location. In order to do this, I use their IP address to identify their country. In order to keep data in the database consistent, I need to make sure I have an accurate IP.

I understand that using META usually uses headers sent by the client's browser, but I don't know if that applies to the `REMOTE_ADDR` attribute.

TLDR: what is the difference between `HttpRequest.get_host()` and `HttpRequest.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between `HttpRequest.get_host()` and `HttpRequest.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` is that the first one checks IP in the following headers in order of decreasing preference:

1. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`
2. `HTTP_HOST`
3. `SERVER_NAME combined with SERVER_PORT`

whereas the second one check the IP in the header `REMOTE_ADDR`.

There is a huge difference in the type of information returned: `get_host()` will give you the name of the server hosting your application, not the IP of the client.

More in detail, here is the implementation of `get_host()`:

```
def get_host(self):
    """Returns the HTTP host using the environment or request headers."""
    # We try three options, in order of decreasing preference.
    if settings.USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST and (
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' in self.META):
        host = self.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
    elif 'HTTP_HOST' in self.META:
        host = self.META['HTTP_HOST']
    else:
        # Reconstruct the host using the algorithm from PEP 333.
        host = self.META['SERVER_NAME']
        server_port = str(self.META['SERVER_PORT'])
        if server_port != ('443' if self.is_secure() else '80'):
            host = '%s:%s' % (host, server_port)

    allowed_hosts = ['*'] if settings.DEBUG else settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS
    domain, port = split_domain_port(host)
    if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):
        return host
    else:
        msg = "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: %r." % host
        if domain:
            msg += "You may need to add %r to ALLOWED_HOSTS." % domain
        raise DisallowedHost(msg)
```

If you want to check for client IP address, here are some headers that could be worth checking (see [Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul)):

- `REMOTE_ADDR`
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`
- `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be comma delimited list of IPs
- `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`
- `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`
- `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`
- `HTTP_FORWARDED`

If you don't know which one to pick (if not all), you could log those headers and pragmatically add new checkings over time.

Comment: Does this really answer the OP's question? I thought it was the differences between the two

Comment: My original answer was not relevant due to a misinterpretation of the code. I hope this one is better.

Comment: This is great. I imagine this was in the Django docs, but I couldn't manage to get a good side by side comparison. Thanks =)