# How to retrieve remote IP address?

Tags: android, http, request, handler

I am developing an Android app with an integrated webserver; in my handler (implements `HttpRequestHandler`) I want to retrieve the remote IP address. How can I do that ?

```
public abstract class MyHttpRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

@Override
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
        HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException, IOException {
 // retrieve remote IP here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to pull the headers off the server? Although not always 100% accurate, refer to this article, it has some headers you can check:

[Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul)