# How to get IP from ContainerRequest JERSEY 1.10 ?

Tags: java, request, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am doing some thing like that:

```
@Override
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) 
{   
    System.out.println("IP ====>>>"+request.getRequestHeader("x-forwarded-for"));

}
```

But I am getting `Null`.

**This version of JERSEY don't  have `request.getRemoteAddr()` method.**

How can I get IP in this version of JERSEY ??

Answer (score 0):

As I see not only x-forwarded-for can contains IP. Try to use other header parameters. [Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul).
ContainerRequest has getRequestHeaders() which returns all headers values. https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequest.html#getRequestHeaders()
You can debug and try to find needed attribute.