# Give user's IP for me - Right now it gives me only 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#

This is how I would like to know what some IP addresses coming in to the website.

Therefore, I would like to get their IP address when possible.

Problem is that I now only get it here: `127.0.0.1.`

The problem is that it happens when the content of the code is located on a server, so give it to me only the information with the IP address. I need the computer's IP or network. it does not matter. I just need the opportunity to Mazes person from the website.

The code that I use to showcase one's ips address it is this:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
Request.Params["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? Request.UserHostAddress
```

The first one gives you the IP if the user is behind a proxy. If it's null, then the second one will give you the right IP.

There are plenty of answered questions about this already. For example:

[Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul)

Comment: Note that X_FORWARDED_FOR can a) Have multiple IP addresses if multiple conforming proxy servers routed the request; b) be missing one or all of the IP addresses of proxy servers that do not set/update that header. I estimate the header is properly set, when appropriate, 99% of the time for normal internet users and 0% of the time for people using proxies to avoid geolocation.

Comment: Thanks for help. I will just look at it and thank you very much for your help. I hope you will give me a +1 for questions and I wish you a great day !!